# C++ - Static List which pops nodes from the head when full

Tags: c++, list

I am looking to implement a list (or any data structure) of size 10 in which I can insert a string. When the list is full it should automatically pop the head off. I want to push the string in the tail.

So for example the list has these elements in it:

"A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"

Now if I call list.insert("K"), the list should look like this:

"B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K"

I know I could possibly build some kind of data structure on my own. But I am wondering if something like this already exists in C++?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, you could just make simple modifications to a `Queue`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is essentially a "circular buffer".
A quick google on this gives a boost implementation:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to do this as a wrapper (adapter) around a deque:

```
template <class T>
class fixed_queue { 
    std::deque<T> items;
    typedef std::deque::size_type size_type;
    size_type max_size;
public:
    fixed_queue(size_type m) max_size(m) {}

    void insert(T const &t) { 
        items.insert(t); 
        if (items.size() > max_size)
            items.erase(0);
    }

    // other stuff here to give whatever access to the contents you need/want.
};
```

Comment: But that would mean that the if (items.size() > max_size) check has to be run for every insertion. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @PiyushGadigone: yes, the way I have it at the moment, you'd do the check at every insertion. If you're really set on getting rid of that, you can do a true circular buffer, where you typically use the modulus operator to avoid a test, but even that doesn't change the situation much (you still need to update the index/pointer to the next_item at an insertion if and only if the buffer is full.

Comment: @PiyushGadigone - the cost of a single `if` is immeasurably small, compared memory allocation that this will do.